# Desktop applications and one online database

Tags: sql-server, distributed

One of our clients has a desktop application and a local SQL Server instance with a database. Now, this client has another office and want to use the system. The problem is that this other office is in another city and the databases have to be synchronized. One solution is not replicate but to put just that database online and, for each application, put in the connection string the IP of the web server where the database is attached.

What do you think about this solution? I'm affraid about security issues.

Comment: VPN, remote office then appears as if they are in local office.

Answer (score 1):

Put database online, and access from several places directly can slow down your system. 
But, if it does not matter, and just caring about security issues, you must not database directly, but create webservice for your database, that run on https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a VPN.  This will address your Security concerns as well as give the remote site access to the DB.  I am guessing the remote site will eventually need access to more then the DB and a VPN gives you the ability to increase access across your network as needed.  Files shares, IM, DB access, and Local WEB apps, will all run within the VPN.

Comment: Thx! So, in your opinion, VPN is the best solution for such scenario (desktop application + multiple access geographically distributed)?

Comment: Yes, a VPN will make it so the remote office/offices appear as if they are in the same building (Speed of connection plays a large part).

Comment: OK, to be better, I can install the system in Amazon EC2 instance and provide access to the clients with Windows Remote Desktop.